# Truncated results when downloading general catalog

Tags: api

I have inherited a project built by another developer that attempts to download and process the general catalog from the Netflix API (REST endpoint: catalog/titles/full?v=2.0). My client is complaining that the results are truncated (maybe even by 50%). I do not receive any error message during the download. Why would the response contain a partial dataset and how might I fix it?

Side note: I couldn't find the NETFLIXAPI tag and don't have enough reputation points to add it. Maybe some else can.

Answer (score 0):

2 points:
1. Up until yesterday I have downloaded the catalog everyday and have never seen it get truncated
2. More importantly, Netflix has deprecated the full catalog and so you need to get catalog/dvd and/or catalog/streaming